# Unauthoried error for all except :manage, :all in cancan of rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, cancan, rails-admin

I am unable to get access for single model or multiple models even `:read`, `:all` but get only access of `:manage`, `:all` in rails_admin.

I have set the authorize_with configuration in rails_admin initializer and add can `:access`, `:rails_admin` and can `:dashboard` after that same problem occurs.

See error in image below:

[image]

Comment: I could not understand you, if you cloud paste your ability.rb please

Comment: thanks for reply i had already solved it

Comment: Could you post the answer please? it would help others